# How to make a Docker container talk to geth on local host

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, web3py, go-ethereum

I have a simple python script using web3 Dockerized and I'm trying to connect to geth.ipc on local host and I can't seem to connect to it. Is there a way to do it?

Python:

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider("/Ethereum/geth.ipc"))
print(f'IPC connected: {web3.isConnected()}')  # want to return True
```

And I'm mounting my `$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc` -> `/Ethereum/geth.ipc`

Comment: Show how you mounted

Comment: How are you running the docker instance? The docs suggest you need something like an `--ipc=host` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc

Comment: `docker run --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/Library/Ethereum,target=/Ethereum container1` I verified that `geth.ipc` file is mounted to the container but can't seem to connect to it

Comment: Adding `--ipc=host` doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: If anyone’s interested, I submitted an issue at geth repo: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mount the folder containing the IPC file rather than mounting the file directly it will work.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? 
It seems to be a problem until this day (https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/483)